# Convert attribute woocommerce terms (taxonomy terms) in posts of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, customization

NEED
I have a list of terms of attributes in woocommerce, specifically WRITERS: list of writers name.
I want to convert writers name in posts of a custom post type, WRITERS. The terms of attribute woocommerce are around 2000.
I would like to automate the insertion.

IDEA
Use wp_insert_post and create a loop that inserts the name of the term of the taxonomy as the title of the post. Is it possible?

```
function convert_attribute_post_type () {
   $terms = get_terms("pa_writers");
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) :


wp_insert_post(array('post_title'=>'$term->name', 'post_type'=>'writers', 'post_content'=>'text'));

   endforeach;
   }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, I believe you are on the right track.

You might wanna add a check if a post already exists with this title, because you're likely to run into some PHP timeout issues with your script. That way you can run the script several times and create all the posts.

You can use the `post_exists()` function for this:

```
if( post_exists( $term->name ) ){
   continue;
} else {
   wp_insert_post($args);
}
```